# How to optionally add a method to a chain in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this chain of methods

```js
MyObject.methodA().methodB().methodC()
```

Suppose I want methodB() to be added or changed based on some condition:

```js
const inclueMethodB = false;
// change method based on condition
MyObject.methodA().(inclueMethodB ? methodB() : method123()).methodC()
// add method based on condition
MyObject.methodA().(inclueMethodB && methodB()).methodC()
```

Is there a way to do this in javascript?

Comment: If you had the method names that you need to call in an array, like `const includeTheseMethods = [ "methodA", "methodB" ]`, then it’s as easy as `includeTheseMethods.reduce((result, methodName) => result[methodName](), MyObject)`.

Comment: Just make the code readable unless you are play code golf

Comment: What do you want to achieve here, and will `methodC` be present on the return value for `methodA`? I mean you could write a function prototype that chains based on a condition and returns a new function, but do you want to pass in the arguments of the previous result, or do you wish to run the method on the result of the previous method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a way to optionally call a method like that.

If you were choosing between two methods, you could use a subscript where the method name is specified dynamically:

```
MyObject.methodA()[includeB1 ? "methodB1" : "methodB2"]().methodC()
```

You could achieve your original goal by defining a method that doesn't do anything except return the same thing that `methodB()` does. If this is a fluent interface where all the methods just return `this`, it could be:

```
doNothing() {
    return this;
}
```

Then you could write:

```
MyObject.methodA()[includeB ? "methodB" : "doNothing"]().methodC()
```

But this all seems unnecessarily complex and confusing. Just use ordinary `if` statements, which express the intent clearly:

```
let temp = MyObject.methodA();
if (includeB) {
    temp = temp.methodB();
}
temp.methodC();
```